# Update_or_create method with unique field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to update or create data in my database by importing a CSV file.

I tested and when I import the CSV file when the "plants" have not already been created it works but when there are the same name of the plants in my database I have an integrity error:

`IntegrityError : duplicate key value violates unique constraint "perma_plants_plant_name_key" DETAIL: Key (name)=(Test bis) already exists.`

So my update_or_create method does not work because in my model the name field must be unique. How can I do to solve this problem?

Here is my model :

```py
class Plant(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my views.py:

```py
class UploadFileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        reader = pd.read_csv(file)
        for _, row in reader.iterrows():
            Plant.objects.update_or_create(
                name=row['Name'],
            )
        return Response({"status": "Success : plants created"},
                        status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to identify the plants, we need a separate field from the name. We could use the default Django "pk" as primary key, but since you want to import it from a CSV, we'll create a "custom_id" on your model:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    custom_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Before adding the primary key, you will probably have to delete all the plants and empty the database so that it will let you do the migrate.

Now your csv should have two columns, "name" and "custom_id", and the views.py would look like this:

```
class UploadFileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        reader = pd.read_csv(file)
        for _, row in reader.iterrows():
            Plant.objects.update_or_create(
                custom_id=row['custom_id'],
                defaults={
                    "name":row['Name'],
                    "custom_id": row['custom_id'],
                }
        return Response({"status": "Success : plants created"},
                        status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

With this code, the actual plant identifier is the "custom_id", which should be fixed and never changed once you assign it.You have to respect it every time you import the CSV. And when you add a new plant, you "invent" a new custom_id (which logically cannot be repeated with any other).

EDIT:

As the `create_or_update` method is not working, try this:

```
class UploadFileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        reader = pd.read_csv(file)
        for _, row in reader.iterrows():
            if Plant.objects.filter(custom_id = row['custom_id']).count() > 0:
                plant = Plant.objects.get(custom_id = row['custom_id'])
                plant.name = row['Name']
            else:
                plant = Plant(
                    name = row['Name'],
                    custom_id = row["custom_id"]
                )
            plant.save()
        return Response({"status": "Success : plants created"},
                        status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case it cannot work because imagine I modify the name of the plant of my CSV file it will not update it in the database and I have other fields than the name to modify or create also...

Comment: You cannot identify a plant just with the name. Because if the name changes, you dont't know if it is a new plant or it is a modification. For what you want to do you need at least one more column in the CSV to help you identify the plant. As you say, with a single "name" field it is impossible.

Comment: Ohh okay thank you but then once I have created another field to identify the plant how can I make my code work and if there is a modification it updates my plant and if it doesn't exist it created it?

Comment: For example, you can use a field we'll call "custom_id", I'll update the answer so you can see what that would look like.

Comment: I just tested your code and I have a problem... When creating it's perfect it works well but if I want to modify the data of a plant and I import the CSV file again it puts me an error: `IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "perma_plants_plant_name_3f4daee3_uniq" DETAIL: Key (name)=(Test) already exists.` Because in my model the field name must be unique...

Comment: Probably you are importing a "name" that exists in the database with a different "custom_id"

Comment: no it was the same normally... I get this error all the time I don't understand how to fix it